# Select 2 ajax call not populating with results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Just downloaded a select2 files from github, the latest release 4.0.3, and i want to populate the options based on what i'm typing (ajax request)

heres the code

```
$('#usernetwork').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'someurl.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {

          return data.items;
        },
        cache: false
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

the url (someurl.php) shows this json result

```
[{"id":"1","text":"ClickWeb"},{"id":"2","text":"ClickWeb 1"},{"id":"3","text":"ClickWeb 2"},{"id":"4","text":"ClickWeb 3"}]
```

and finally the select field is this

```
<select name="usernetwork" id="usernetwork" class="form-control">
</select>
```

this is the very first time i try this for now im getting nothing as query (for test purposes)

The results are not showing up, and i have no idea on how to fix this, any tips?

Comment: try using an empty option: <select name="usernetwork" id="usernetwork" class="form-control">
</select><option value=""></option></select>

Comment: Didnt worked, its not even loading as before

Comment: try  `processResults: function (data, page) { return data; }` in json result not isset `items`

Comment: still no results, replaced "data.items" with "data" and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my answer the only thing you need to change is your return statement inside processResults callback like this

```
return {
          results: data

       };
```

Here is full code :

```
         $('#usernetwork').select2({
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'someurl.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        data: function (params) {
                            return {
                                q: params.term, // search term
                                page: params.page
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function (data, page) {

                             return {
                                results: data

                              };
                        },
                        cache: false
                    },
                    minimumInputLength: 1
                });
```

Comment: Did, not worked, select2 is loading correctly, i can pre populate it, but no success in this

Comment: Right console.log(data) in processResults before return statement and check what your php script response.

Comment: i guess the data is not even being submited, nothing is being returned in console.log, what do you think?

Comment: Does it make a request to server or not ? check your console

Comment: No result from the console: heres the processResults code:
processResults: function (data, page) {
      console.log(data);
            return {
                 results: data
             };
        }

Comment: It seems like the request is not send to server when you start typing in search box. Have you check your console for network request to sample.php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122541/discussion-between-user3273700-and-paulo-jose-oliveira-rosa).

Comment: @PauloJoséOliveiraRosa did you found any solution to your problem? I am getting data from the server and did console.log. but it does not populate results in select with all options